# Berndt–Hall–Hall–Hausman algorithm does not work

Tags: algorithm, mle, log-likelihood

I am studying economics and trying to use BHHH algorithm to maximize the loglikelihood function. However, the algorithm converges immediately since the absolute value of approximate Hessian is too large compared with the magnitude of the derivatives. This might happen when the starting point is far from the optimal. But I have the feeling it will also happen when the magnitude of loglikelihood is large and so is the derivative. Am I right? In this case, which algorithm should be a better option? Thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question seems not to be about a programming problem.

Comment: This is a question about algorithms. Even though it is not about coding itself, I think it might be helpful for people who are learning optimization algorithms.